# Multithreading issue ,Maybe a DeadLock using Foreach

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

`Parallel.ForEach` keeps on running and my program does not end. I am unable to trace where it goes after the first iteration. My guess is that gets a deadlock and keeps on doing context switching.

```
private void ReadInputFile()
{
    var collection = new ConcurrentBag<PropertyRecord>();
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(InputFileName);
    int i = 0;
    int RecordsCount = lines.Count();
    Parallel.ForEach(lines, line =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            return;                    
        }

        var tokens = line.Split(',');
        var postalCode = tokens[0];
        var country = tokens.Length > 1 ? tokens[1] : "england";

        SetLabelNotifyTwoText(
            string.Format(
                "Reading PostCode {0} out of {1}"
                i,
                lines.Length));

        var tempRecord = GetAllAddesses(postalCode, country);
        if (tempRecord != null)
        {
            foreach (PropertyRecord r in tempRecord)
            {
                collection.Add(r);
            }
        }    
    });
}

private List<PropertyRecord> GetAllAddesses(
        string postalCode,
        string country = "england")
{
    SetLabelNotifyText("");
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar1.Update();

    var records = new List<PropertyRecord>();
    using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
    {
        var url = CreateUrl(postalCode, country);
        var document = w.DownloadString(url);
        var pagesCount = GetPagesCount(document);
        if (pagesCount == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++)
        {
            SetLabelNotifyText(
                string.Format(
                    "Reading Page {0} out of {1}",
                    i,
                    pagesCount - 1));

            url = CreateUrl(postalcode,country, i);
            document = w.DownloadString(url);
            var collection = Regex.Matches(
                document,
                "<div class=\"soldDetails\">(.|\\n|\\r)*?class=" +
                "\"soldAddress\".*?>(?<address>.*?)(</a>|</div>)" +
                "(.|\\n|\\r)*?class=\\\"noBed\\\">(?<noBed>.*?)" +
                "</td>|</tbody>");

            foreach (var match in collection)
            {
                var r = new PropertyRecord();

                var bedroomCount = match.Groups["noBed"].Value;
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bedroomCount))
                {
                    r.BedroomCount = bedroomCount;             
                }
                else
                {
                    r.BedroomCount = "-1";
                }

                r.address = match.Groups["address"].Value;

                var line = string.Format(
                    "\"{0}\",{1}",
                    r.address
                    r.BedroomCount);
                OutputLines.Add(line);

                Records.Add(r);
            }
        }
    }

    return Records;
}
```

It runs fine without `Parallel.ForEach`, but using `Parallel.ForEach` is in requirements.

I have debugged it and after returning from `GetAllAdresses`-method first time, *Step Next* button halts and it just keep on debugging in the background. It doesn't come back on any bookmark I have placed.

Comment: it will be even harder to debug from here.

Comment: I have debugged it ,and first time returning from GetAllAddresses(..) it goes ,i dont know where

Comment: Use debugger please. Also what does `SetLabelNotifyText` and `SetLabelNotifyTwoText` does? Does that calls `control.Invoke`? and which thread calls is that Main thread?

Comment: Yes they are there to stop illegel Thread Access issue to update GUI

Comment: just hit pause in debugger and open up the (parallel) threads/task window, just saying!

Comment: @Charlie Please when you post code on StackOverflow make it a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example you could at the very least remove all the lines of code you have commented out. It makes it easier for people to read and therefore help you.

Comment: thanks @dav_i ,i will do it

Comment: -, MSDN: [Walkthrough: Debugging a Parallel Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943.aspx) (which will guide you to the magic of Visual Studio and its debugger ... and the Tasks-window)

Comment: Thanks @AndreasNiedermair ,I am reading it ,Kindly look at the code , You may find the problem , in basics

Comment: @Charlie Glad to help, but that's definitely no remote-debugging session for us here! please do *your* homework and investigate the running tasks/threads/stacks yourself! It is very unlikely that there'll be an answer which pinpoints the very line that troubles you, as this question does not follow [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said in comments, your `SetLabelNotifyText` and `SetLabelNotifyTwoText` methods calls `Control.Invoke`.

For `Control.Invoke` to work, Main thread has to be free, but in your case you seem to block the main thread by invoking `Parallel.ForEach` in it.

Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 100), (i) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);//Simulate some work
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => SetText(i)));
    });
}

private void SetText(int i)
{
    textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Main thread waits for `Parallel.ForEach` and worker threads waits for Main thread, and thus results in deadlock.

How to fix: Don't use `Invoke` simply use `BeginInvoke` or don't block the MainThread.

<sub>If this isn't the case post [sscce](http://sscce.org/), that will be helpful for us</sub>

Comment: @Charlie, use `async` and `await`, it allows the threads to yield to the scheduler when you are downloading from the web client, if you use `DownloadStringTaskAsync`.

Comment: i wanted to ask how will i update Document String (html) of particular thread from async DownloadString Event Handler from where i have called it  .

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this, to use  [`async` and `await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx). This is the modern alternative to using `BeginInvoke` and other asynchronous code models.

```
private async Task ReadInputFile()
{
    var collection = new ConcurrentBag<PropertyRecord>();
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(InputFileName);
    int i = 0;
    int RecordsCount = lines.Count();
    Parallel.ForEach(lines, line =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            return;                    
        }

        var tokens = line.Split(',');
        var postalCode = tokens[0];
        var country = tokens.Length > 1 ? tokens[1] : "england";

        SetLabelNotifyTwoText(
            string.Format(
                "Reading PostCode {0} out of {1}"
                i,
                lines.Length));

        var tempRecord = await GetAllAddesses(postalCode, country);
        if (tempRecord != null)
        {
            foreach (PropertyRecord r in tempRecord)
            {
                collection.Add(r);
            }
        }    
    });
}

private async Task<List<PropertyRecord>> GetAllAddesses(
        string postalCode,
        string country = "england")
{
    SetLabelNotifyText("");
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar1.Update();

    var records = new List<PropertyRecord>();
    using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
    {
        var url = CreateUrl(postalCode, country);
        var document = await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
        var pagesCount = GetPagesCount(document);
        if (pagesCount == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++)
        {
            SetLabelNotifyText(
                string.Format(
                    "Reading Page {0} out of {1}",
                    i,
                    pagesCount - 1));

            url = CreateUrl(postalcode,country, i);
            document = await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
            var collection = Regex.Matches(
                document,
                "<div class=\"soldDetails\">(.|\\n|\\r)*?class=" +
                "\"soldAddress\".*?>(?<address>.*?)(</a>|</div>)" +
                "(.|\\n|\\r)*?class=\\\"noBed\\\">(?<noBed>.*?)" +
                "</td>|</tbody>");

            foreach (var match in collection)
            {
                var r = new PropertyRecord();

                var bedroomCount = match.Groups["noBed"].Value;
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bedroomCount))
                {
                    r.BedroomCount = bedroomCount;             
                }
                else
                {
                    r.BedroomCount = "-1";
                }

                r.address = match.Groups["address"].Value;

                var line = string.Format(
                    "\"{0}\",{1}",
                    r.address
                    r.BedroomCount);
                OutputLines.Add(line);

                Records.Add(r);
            }
        }
    }

    return Records;
}
```

Then call it like this

```
ReadInputFile.Wait();
```

or, even better, is the caller is `async`,

```
await ReadInputFile();
```

Comment: +1 Your *Then call it like this* should be `await ReadInputFile()`. Don't mix asynchronous and synchronous code. Do it async all the way(if possible).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, that would be better but, the calling method would need to be `async`.

Comment: Yes, Most probably OP will have this code somewhere in button click or from some user interface. Which means that event handler can be marked as `async` so you can `await` inside it. I know it is not possible always, that's why I wrote *(if possible)*